# Motorola EMDK - Thread blocking issues using Barcode2 ScanBufferStart and ScanBufferStop

Tags: multithreading, compact-framework, barcode, motorola-emdk

I am using the Symbol.Barcode2 object in the Motorola EMDK 2.7.  I am using the asynchronous Buffered Scan mode.  Here is some sample code that attaches a delegate to be called for each scan event, and then starts the scanner in asynchronous buffer mode:

```
Barcode2 symbolBarcode2 = new Barcode2(Symbol.Barcode2.Devices.SupportedDevices[0]);
symbolBarcode2.OnScan +=new Barcode2.OnScanHandler(symbolBarcode2_OnScan);
symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStart();
```

To stop the scanner I call the ScanBufferStop method:

```
symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStop();
```

I use the ScanBufferStop in two scenarios:

First, when processing the data and I want to stop the scanner and alert the user.  Example:

```
private void symbolReader_OnScan(ScanDataCollection scancollection)
{
    if (scancollection.GetFirst.Text == "0000000000")
    {
        // Turn off scanner and alert user
        symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStop();
    }
    else
    {
        // Process data and wait for next scan
    }
}
```

Second, when the application closes.

My issue is that when ScanBufferStop is called the application freezes.  Debugging and examining the Call Stack shows that inside the Symbol.Barcode2.Barcode2.ScanBufferStop() there is a call to WaitOne():

```
mscorlib.dll!System.PInvoke.PAL.Threading_Event_Wait(System.IntPtr handle = 1245201)    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.WaitOne() + 0x7 bytes 
Symbol.Barcode2.dll!Symbol.Barcode2.Barcode2.ScanBufferStop() + 0x43 bytes
```

I can also see that there are additional threads being creating by the Symbol object.  I think what is going on is that the ScanBufferStop() is checking to see if another thread is accessing the Barcode2 object, and if so calling WaitOne.  But when I call it from the same thread in the delegate, it results in a deadlock scenario.

I was able to get around it in the first scenario by creating my own new thread that calls the ScannBufferStop from a delegate:

```
private void symbolReader_OnScan(ScanDataCollection scancollection)
{
    if (scancollection.GetFirst.Text == "0000000000")
    {
        // Turn off scanner and alert user
        //symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStop();
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(StopDelegate);
        t.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        // Process data and wait for next scan
    }
}

internal void StopDelegate()
{
    symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStop();
}
```

But I still have a dead lock issue when the application exits.  I tried to use the same technique of calling the ScanBufferStop from a different thread but it still ends up with one thread that is hung with a call to WaitOne().

I have also tried calling 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
but that did not help.

Does anyone have any similar experience with the Buffered Scan Mode, or maybe general threading/locking issues that might have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should not be using the buffered mode of scanning.  It is really intended for the scenario where the user is scanning as fast as possible and the application is effectively just consuming the scans from the buffer, as opposed to the IMO more common approach where each scan is received by the application and validated immediately.  In the buffered mode, the user could be 2 or 3 scans ahead of your validation routine, which obviously doesn't work out well.

In fact, I found this in the SDK docos in regards to buffered scanning:

> Caution: The buffered scanning mode may not be suitable for those
>   applications that require validating each scan before proceeding to
>   reading the next barcode.

Intsead of `symbolBarcode2.ScanBufferStart()` use `symbolBarcode2.Scan()`.  It is still async, just not buffered.

Comment: We started by using the .Scan() and calling it in the event each time.  From a validation perspective this works great as you can guarantee that no barcode will be scanned after the "bad" one.  But our issue was we still wanted to let the user scan as fast as possible.  We optimized our validation logic down to < 1ms.  I even put the call to .Scan() as the first line in the scan event and the user can pull the trigger faster than when the scanner is ready again.  And if they pull the trigger too early, the laser does not come on at all until they fully release and pull again.

Comment: Have you tried the Pause/Resume variants to see if they are more tolerant of being called from within a callback?

Comment: The EMDK is obfuscated, but I can read enough to see that it is waiting on an `ManualResetEvent` that, under just the right conditions, is `Set` in the read loop.  It also looks like there are a dozen ways *not* to call the `Set`, so hopefully they watched their logic closely.  One thought from skimming the code, have you tried calling `ScanBufferClear` before the Stop and/or Resume?  Perhaps it is trying to call you back with whatever is left in the buffer before stopping, which would certainly deadlock.

Comment: OK, tried calling ScanBufferClear.  Looking at the call stack, ScanBufferClear calls ScanBufferPause, which then calls WaitOne...  So no luck there...

Comment: I found that calling ScanBufferStop() directly in the _Closing() event did not cause a deadlock.  I was using the same technique of calling it from a thread which was necessary from the scan delegate.
I also found timing issues if I did any synchronous UI operations in the scan event delegate.  For example a messagebox.  It would not call the ScanBufferStop untill after the messagebox was closed which kind of defeats the purpose.  I was able to get around this however by calling the scan event also from another thread.  So far this is working well.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Pretty nasty bug (or lack of doco disclaimer) that you cannot affect the scanner from within the callback.